# Package for formatting numeric values in reproducible research

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, reproducible-research

Is there a standard way of converting numeric values to character with a particular type of formatting applied.

I'm thinking of something like:

```
formatR(32390,"dollars")
# returns "$32,390"
formatR(1.25,"percent")
# returns "125%"
```

Obviously, not so hard to write them myself, but the need for this kind of thing is pretty constant in when preparing reports, and there must be some package out there already?

Comment: scales has some formatters, I think

Comment: @baptiste Indeed it does.  `comma`, `dollar`, and `percent`.  Care to post as an answer?

Comment: it's against my work ethics, but since you asked :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `scales` package provides a few formatting functions,

```
> scales::percent(c(1.2, 0.13))
[1] "120%" "13%" 
> scales::dollar(c(1.2, 0.13))
[1] "$1.20" "$0.13"
> scales::comma(c(1.2, 0.13))
[1] "1.20" "0.13"
> scales::comma(scales::dollar(6000.88))
[1] "$6,000.88"
```